# Send large video file by file_id with telegram bot

Tags: python, video, telegram-bot

I'm using python and telebotAPI for my bot and I noticed that the command `bot.send_video(chat_id, open(file_name, 'rb'))` only sends videos smaller than 10mb, is there a way to send very large video files?

UPDATE:
After some comments I read in the telegram documentation: if the file is already stored somewhere on the Telegram servers, you don't need to reupload it: each file object has a file_id field, simply pass this file_id as a parameter instead of uploading. There are no limits for files sent this way. So how I can send a video to the telegram server and then send the file_id to the chat?

Comment: limits here.... https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files you may be able to send as a file?

Comment: could you provide me an example? @Offbeatmammal

Comment: [Docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files) : "Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for other files."

Comment: @0stone0 is there a way to send videos larger than 50 mb? since, for example, in a normal chat between two telegram users, a user may send video even large video without errors to the other party

Comment: @james I dont think there is. You should probably look at a third party way. If i use `sendDocument` to send a 58MB mp4 file, Telegram gives me a **413 Request Entity Too Large**

Comment: I read in the telegram documentation that: If the file is already stored somewhere on the Telegram servers, you don't need to reupload it: each file object has a file_id field, simply pass this file_id as a parameter instead of uploading. There are no limits for files sent this way. So how I can send a video to the telegram server and then send the file_id to the chat? @0stone0

Comment: Using the `file_id` will not fix the max-size problem you are facing. 
Example: Send a picture with `/sendFile`, Telegram will answer with a `file_id`, you could store this somewhere if you wish the resend that file. `bot.send_photo(chat_id, file_id)` [TelebotApi](https://ma24th.github.io/telebotapi/) shows quite some examples!

Answer (score 1):

There is an attribute in send_video function as 'timeout'. By default timeout is 20s. If you need more time for sending your video, set it at your desired time in seconds. For example:

```
bot.send_video(chat_id='receiver chat id', video=open(file_name, 'rb')), timeout=10000)
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I am not sure about limitations. I think it depends on if you are a client, bot or an api user.

Answer (score 0):

To send using 'file_id' - for example, send file to the bot, the bot will trigger callback, find the remoteFile there, and take id - it will look something like this

```
AAMCAgADGQEAAqCnXv7lHCkd-2Br08TSugdUR45LVyIAAnoIABJctPlLDk4X8ug8tDcaMSmVLgADAQAHbQADoKoAAhgE
```